# Nautilus: How to adjust font on the left side panel and the icons

Tags: nautilus, icons, fonts

Please see in this pic, I have adjust the general font due to 4K screen, but not sure how to adjust the font on the left side panel as well as the top panel icons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Install Gnome Tweaks if you did not already. On the "Fonts" tab, you can increase the font scaling factor. This will increase the fonts of the user interface.

In fact, play with combinations of Settings - Displays - Scale and Gnome Tweaks - Font scaling until you find a combination that works best (e.g. Scaling factor 1 with a larger font scaling, or Scaling factor 2 in combination with a reduced font scaling...)

Comment: Thanks, for the font it works, and what about the icons?

Comment: See my answer, scaling factor

Comment: Tried, didn't work.